# Allow users to passwordless su to more than one user

Tags: sudo, users, su

Assuming I want `user1` to be able to passwordless `su` to `someuser`, I add to `/etc/sudoers.d/custom`

```
user1 ALL=(someuser) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

What is the syntax to **also** allow the same for `anotheruser`?

Following did not work

```
user1 ALL=(someuser,anotheruser) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

after that use from user1 to switch

```
sudo su - someuser
```

Comment: Ι just want for `user1` and `someuser`

Comment: to add another user use the same in next line and change the username, you can also give sudoers rights to a group then add members in the group, %somegroup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL